# Open 100 files in R

Tags: r, file

I need to read many files with data, but I can't make it work.

For example: I have 6 ASCII files named "rain,wind, etc..."

This is what I thought:

```
namelist<-c("rain","wind","sunshine hour","radiation","soil moisture","pressure")
for (i in 1:6){
 metedata<-read.table('d:/namelist[i].txt')
 metedata
}
```

But that didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
namelist<-c("rain","wind","sunshine hour","radiation","soil moisture","pressure")
for (name in namelist){
 metedata<-read.table(paste0('d:/',name,'.txt')
 metedata
}
```

Comment: But this will overwrite `metedata` on each cycle thru the loop.  Maybe make it a list, so `metedata[[j]]<-read.table(paste0('d:\',namelist[j],'.txt')` .Basically what Paul wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Or read them into a list using `lapply`. Assuming your working directory is in the location of the files:

```
dat = lapply(list.files(pattern = "txt"), read.table)
```

this makes a list of all the `.txt` files in your working directory, and call `read.table` on them, returning a list of their contents.

Or directly read them into one big data.frame:

```
library(plyr)
dat = ldply(list.files(pattern = "txt"), read.table)
```